# Strange "missing \item" problem in enumerate

Tags: errors, enumerate

According to [this website](http://texblog.org/2008/10/16/lists-enumerate-itemize-description-and-how-to-change-them/), the following should work:

```
\begin{enumerate}[I]
    \item foobar
\end{enumerate}
```

Yet, I always get the same error, with any of the `[]` options:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.143   \item f
              oobar
?
```

When I leave the `[]` options out, I get no error whatsoever, and it works like it should. I need to use capital Roman letters as symbols though, so I need to solve this problem.

Does anybody know what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the `enumerate` package? It doesn't seem so.

Comment: Check the website: `\usepackage{enumerate}`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like that was the problem. I thought I already had the package loaded, because `enumerate` was working.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans The basic `enumerate` environment is built in to LaTeX, but without the extras provided by the `enumerate` package.